# Problem with printing first 10 rows of a file

Tags: c, file

So I am trying to make a function print_file_rows() that prints the first ten rows of a file. If the file has more than 10 rows it works perfectly fine but if there's 10 or less it starts printing garbage. Any ideas on how I can fix this? (MUST ONLY USE THE SYSTEM FUNCTIONS OPEN/READ/WRITE/CLOSE)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void print_file_rows(char *path)
{
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t size = 100;
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t res;
    char *buff = malloc(size);

    while((res = read(fd, buff + offset, 100)) != 0)
    {
        offset += res;
        if (offset + 100 > size)
        {
            size *= 2;
            buff = realloc(buff, size);
        }
    }

    close(fd);

    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0;buff[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(j == 10)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(buff[i] == '\n')
        {
            j++;
        }
        printf("%c", buff[i]);
    }

    free(buff);
}

int main()
{
    print_file_rows("a.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `read()` does not terminate the buffer with a `zero` byte. You have to do that yourself *manually*. When file has more than 10 lines (more than 10 `'\n'`) your loop `breaks`, otherwise it starts reading past the end of the string (into *garbage*/UB area) because there is no terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not terminate the buffer with a zero byte"? How can I terminate it?

Comment: [Similar question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69857033/2505965) (same class?).

Comment: In order to write 10 lines, you don't have to read all 100,000,000 or however many are there lines in. That's just a ton of wasted memory and disk access.

Answer (score 0):

From [`man 2 read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html):

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   #include <unistd.h>
>
>   ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
> read()  attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd into the buffer starting at buf.

`read` is for reading raw bytes, and as such has no notion of [*strings*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). It does not place a NUL terminating byte (`'\0'`) at the end of the buffer. If you are going to treat the data you read as a string, you must terminate the buffer yourself.

To make room for this NUL terminating byte you should always allocate one extra byte in your buffer (*i.e.,* read one less byte that your maximum).

We can see the return value is actually of type `ssize_t`, rather than `size_t`, which allows for

> On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set to indicate the  error.

This means we will need to check that the return value is greater than zero, rather than not zero which would cause the offset to be *decremented* on error.

With all that said, note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69857365/2505965) from a similar question posted just yesterday shows how to achieve this without the use of a dynamic buffer. You can simply read the file one byte at a time and stop reading when you've encountered 10 newline characters.

---

If you do want to understand how to read a file into a dynamic buffer, then here is an example using the calculated `offset` to NUL terminate the buffer as it grows. Note that reading the entire file this way is inefficient for this task (especially for a large file).

(Note: the call to `write`, instead of `printf`)

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_file_rows(const char *path)
{
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);

    const size_t read_size = 100;
    size_t size = read_size;
    size_t offset = 0;
    ssize_t res;
    char *buff = malloc(size + 1);

    while ((res = read(fd, buff + offset, read_size)) > 0) {
        offset += res;

        buff[offset] = '\0';

        if (offset + read_size > size) {
            size *= 2;
            buff = realloc(buff, size + 1);
        }
    }

    close(fd);

    int lines = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; lines < 10 && buff[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buff[i], 1);

        if (buff[i] == '\n')
            lines++;
    }

    free(buff);
}

int main(void)
{
    print_file_rows("a.txt");
}
```

*(Error handling omitted for code brevity. `malloc`, `realloc`, and `open` can all fail, and should normally be handled.)*

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any buffers. It is most likely buffered on the OS level so you may print char by char.

```
int print_file_rows(char *path, size_t nrows)
{
    int result = -1;
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    char c;
    if (fd > 0)
    {
        while(nrows && read(fd, &c, 1) == 1)
        {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, 1);
            if(c == `\n`) nrows--;
        }
        result = nrows;
    }
    close(fd);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    if(print_file_rows("a.txt", 10) == -1)
        printf("Something has gone wrong\n");
    return 0;
}
```